# Table Element Not Taking 100% Of Parent Element

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I created a sample of the situation in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x11joex11/r5spu85z/1/)

I updated JSFiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/x11joex11/r5spu85z/8/ (this shows in more detail how the sticky footer works so well, just height issue).

I want the table to take up the remaining height, for some reason the `height: 100%` is not working?

From my tests it appears to be related to `min-height: 100%`. I need that to make the sticky footer work.

So a solution for me is another way to do the sticky footer, or a way to still give 100% height to the elements within.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper_content">
    <!--Header-->
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="content table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="l_cell">left</div>
        <div class="r_cell">right</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Footer-->
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -50px;
    background-color: black;
}

.container {
}

.table {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.l_cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 265px;
    background-color: orange;
}

.r_cell {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: purple;
}

.header {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
}

.push {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/r5spu85z/2/

Comment: yes except that the scroll bar doesn't continue down the page.

Comment: thanks for the attempt though! Where did the text for left and right go also? *edit* getting rid of push helps the scrollbar, but not sure where the text went?

Comment: beneath header, I positioned absolute and forgot to add padding to container to push them down

Comment: I added padding to the TD's to see them but the sticky footer doesn't work now, any ideas to make it work? If you shrink the size of the page you will see the sticky footer goes through the text instead of stopping at it.  Here is the JSFiddle with the edits (http://jsfiddle.net/x11joex11/r5spu85z/4/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x11joex11/r5spu85z/6/, here is another update to better show the issue, it goes through the header also.  In my original JSFiddle you will see the desired behavior.  Please let me know if you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my problem for now, but it requires the use of display:table which I recall causes other errors down the road, but it does appear to work right now to create the layout I had in mind.

http://jsfiddle.net/x11joex11/r5spu85z/10/

**CSS**

```
body,html{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
.wrapper{}
.table{
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   display:table;
   background-color:yellow;
}
.row{display:table-row;}
.cell{display:table-cell;}
.footer{background-color:green;height:50px;}
.header{background-color:red;height:30px;}
.left{background-color:purple;}
.right{background-color:orange;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper table">
    <div class="header row">
        Header<br/>
        Header2
    </div>
    <div class="content table">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell left">leftt<br/>left2</div>
            <div class="cell right">right<br/>right2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer row">
        Footer
        <br/>
        Footer2
    </div>
</div>
```

An answer not requiring the use of display:table or table tags is preferred.

**Notice the sticky footer effect remains.**

Comment: I should note, that while working in this I ran into a slew of issues if I tried to set column widths with 'width'.  The proper way is to instead use 'min-width'.  This helped with a jQuery animation I was doing to animate the left column to be shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution, http://jsfiddle.net/7t4RT/

This question has been asked many times before. I recommend viewing some of the answers already provided here at StackOverflow.

The reason that we're unable to use `height: 100%` in your example is because no height has defined. The CSS is wondering... well how high is 100%? There are many ways to get our elements to fill their containers in either HTML or CSS. Simply choose one you feel works better for you.

The following is one of many ways to solve this problem.

HTML:

```
<div class="fill-height">
    <p>Filled</p>
</div>
<div class="cant-fill-height">
    <p>Not Filled</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.fill-height {
    background-color: #0ff;
    width: 200px;    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.cant-fill-height {
    background-color: #ff0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind, could you show how this would work in my example while retaining the sticky footer? Thanks by the way for the answer!